# First click on select doesn't selecting the value

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hello i got problem with my select box in HTML. First click on this box sometimes doesn't selecting the value but only "focusing" it? (i don't know that this is a good word for it)
I made screen to help You explain what i mean:

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjyIL.png)

What can i do to avoid this? When user will click i have to show the right place on the map

Some parts of my code:

```
echo '<select id="selector'.$i.'" style=" height: 100%; width: 228px; margin: 2px;" onchange="JumpToPoint(this.value);">';
while($street = mysql_fetch_array($streets, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
   echo '<option value="'.$street['x'].','.$street['y'].'">'.$street['name'].'</option>';        
}
echo '</select></div>';
```

It is any possibility to simulate this focus ? Because only first click is focusing value - the socond, third etc always selecting the right value

I found that the problem is with this function:

```
    jQuery.fn.filterByText = function(textbox) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var select = this;
        var options = [];
        $(select).find('option').each(function() {
            options.push({value: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text()});
        });
        $(select).data('options', options);

        $(textbox).bind('change keyup', function() {
            var options = $(select).empty().data('options');
            var search = $.trim($(this).val());
            var regex = new RegExp(search,"gi");

            $.each(options, function(i) {
                var option = options[i];
                if(option.text.match(regex) !== null) {
                    $(select).append(
                        $('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value)
                    );
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```

But i don't know where

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Could you please post the code,

Comment: u need Javascript man

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you don't just use the 'change' event for your jQuery event instead of the 'click' event so going with the code you put up and assuming you are using jQuery try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#selector<?php echo $i ?>').change(function() {
      /** change map code goes here **/
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: He is using the onchange event if you look at the code he is just calling it inline on the element `onchange="JumpToPoint(this.value);`

Comment: you are right sorry ! unfortunately I can't really help him much further without more information.

Answer (score 0):

add this line before while loop.I think this helps u.

echo '---select----';